# admin group disappeared; cannot groupadd

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, file-permissions, sudo

Okay, so this is embarrassing, but I seem to have lost the admin group on my machine, though I would have sworn I hadn't gone anywhere near it.  I'm running Mint Maya.

Trying to innocently `sudo` this morning (to`update-alternatives`) I got the response:

```
kate is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

I can get to a root shell from the boot menu, thankfully, and `/etc/sudoers` looks fine, but it refers to admin and `/etc/group` doesn't contain it.  (I can only assume it used to; I never had any problem with sudo before today.)  Trying to recreate an admin group with `groupadd admin` (as root) gives me this:

```
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
```

I can't find any `.lock` files in `/etc`, and I've run out of Google leads, so I'm really at a loss.

UPDATE: The locking issue may be because the boot root shell is read-only.

Comment: Try `mount -w -o remount /` to get the root filesystem out of readonly mode

Comment: I've just tried the fsck recovery boot menu option which seemed to do just that, getting it out of readonly mode.  Thank you. *phew!*

Answer (score 0):

Running `fsck` first mounted `/` in read/write mode, which allowed me to `groupadd admin`, `usermod -a -G admim` myself, and regain `sudo` privileges.